# PHP multiple elements inside stdclass array (JSON)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array inside a object, I want to add multiple values to the array, but my codes start to seperates them. The response should like this:

```
{
    "requestTime": "1",
    "clients": [{
        "name": "Peter",
        "id": 905
    }]
}
```

But instead of this it looks like this:

```
{
    "requestTime": "1",
    "clients": [{
        "name": "Peter"
    }, {
        "id": 905
    }]
}
```

My Code:

```
$myObj = new stdClass();

$myObj->requestTime = $reqtime;
$myObj->clients[]->id = $id;
$myObj->clients[]->name = $name;

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like that:

```
$myObj->clients[] = ['id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name]
```

Answer (score 2):

Build the array all in one go, rather than in 2 steps which will generate 2 arrays.

```
$myObj = new stdClass();

$myObj->requestTime = $reqtime;
$myObj->clients[] = ['id' => $id, 'name' => $name];

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: But Sir, this doesn't match the output that OP wants it returns something like this `{"requestTime":1,"clients":{"id":905,"name":"Peter"}}`

Comment: `$myObj->clients` should be `$myObj->clients[]` I think

Comment: @don'tangryme I thought I had written that. Woops

Answer (score 0):

**If I understood your requirements as per your required output** then this will work for you, use variable instead in place of static `id`, `name` and `requestTime` variable that I used.

```
<?php  
 $myObj = new stdClass();
 $myObj->requestTime = 1;
 $myObj->clients[] = ['id' => 905, 'name' => 'Peter'];
 $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
 echo $myJSON;
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{ 
 "requestTime": 1, 
 "clients": [{
   "id": 905, 
   "name": "Peter" 
  }] 
 }
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/T9W88